# Why is my code skipping over certain elements in a txt file?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, file-io

I'm currently working on an assignment that requires me to build a small database for an imaginary toy company. They sell four different types of toys, with all of their toy's data in a single text file. Different toys have varying attributes to them.

My job is to read every line of the text file, find out what toy it is based on it's serial number, create a new instance of that toy, and load it into an array list of Toys.

Here are some examples of a line in the .txt file for every type of toy.

**Animal**

> 2835360879;Cow;Game Assassin;19.52;3;7;Plastic;M

**Puzzle**

> 4353818087;Eight queens puzzle;Gamescape;15.69;5;6;C

**Figure**

> 1147205649;Ninja Turtles;Gamezoid;46.15;10;6;A

**Board Game**

> 7235647474;13 Dead End Drive;Game Assassin;55.18;10;9;1-8;Emeli Davis

The following method is in charge of parsing through the text file, to create new instances of Toy, and to add them into the Array List

```
public void loadData() {
        
        try {
            File dataFile = new File("res/toys.txt");
            
            if (dataFile.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Data file created!");
            }
            
            else {
                
                Scanner readData = new Scanner(dataFile);
                readData.useDelimiter(";"); // sets semicolons as the delimiter
                
                while(readData.hasNext()) {
                    
                    sn = readData.nextDouble(); // reads the next double (serial number) on each line
                    category = categoryHandler(sn); // setting and returning value for category based on the serial number
                    
                    nm = readData.next(); // initializes the name of the toy
                    brd = readData.next();
                    prc = readData.nextDouble();
                    availableCnt = readData.nextInt();
                    ageApp = readData.nextInt();
                    
                    // creates a new object, dependant on the category
                    switch(category) {
                        
                        case "Figures":
                            
                            char classification = readData.next().charAt(0);
                            Figure figures = new Figure(sn, nm, brd, prc, availableCnt, ageApp, classification);
                            data.add(figures);
                            break;
                        case "Animals":
                            
                            String material = readData.next();
                            char size = readData.next().charAt(0);
                            Animal animals = new Animal(sn, nm, brd, prc, availableCnt, ageApp, material, size);
                            data.add(animals);
                            break;
                        case "Puzzles":
                            char puzzleType = readData.next().charAt(0);
                            Puzzle puzzles = new Puzzle(sn, nm, brd, prc, availableCnt, ageApp, puzzleType);
                            data.add(puzzles);
                            break;
                        case "Board Games":
                            
                            String playerCount = readData.next(); // holds the player count as a string
                            
                            int minPlayers = Integer.parseInt(playerCount.substring(0, 1)); // holds the first integer
                            int maxPlayers = Integer.parseInt(playerCount.substring(playerCount.length() - 1, playerCount.length())); // holds the second integer
                            
                            String designers = "";
                            
                            BoardGame boardGames = new BoardGame(sn, nm, brd, prc, availableCnt, ageApp, minPlayers, maxPlayers, designers);
                            data.add(boardGames);
                            break;
                            
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid toy type selected!");
                    }
                    
                    if (readData.hasNext()) {
                        readData.nextLine(); // skips to the next line if there's a line to skip to
                    }
            
                }
                readData.close();
            }
        }   
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

The following method is in charge of categorizing the toy type.

```
public String categoryHandler(double serialNumber) {
        
        String serialNumCheck = Double.toString(serialNumber); // converting serial number to string to allow the first digit to be checked
        double firstDigit;
        // setting up the first digit, checking to see if it's zero.
        if (serialNumCheck.length() == 12) {
            firstDigit = 0;
        }
        else {
            firstDigit = Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(serialNumber).substring(0, 1));
        }
        
        // conditionals 
        if (firstDigit == 0 || firstDigit == 1) {
            category = "Figures";
        }
        
        else if (firstDigit == 2 || firstDigit == 3) {
            category = "Animals";
        }
        
        else if (firstDigit == 4 || firstDigit == 5 || firstDigit == 6) {
            category = "Puzzles";
        }
        
        else if (firstDigit == 7 || firstDigit == 8 || firstDigit == 9) {
            category = "Board Games";
        }
        
        // this condition should not be possible to achieve, unless the first digit is negative. Still have it just in case.
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid serial number created!");
            category = "";
        }
        
        return category;
    }
```

After running the loadData() method, my array list only contains 128 toys, instead of the expected 225. Almost all of them are categorized properly, but a few toys are not, at seemingly at random indices.

I suspect it has something to with readData.nextLine() at the end of the loadData() method. The problem is that when I remove the line, the program throws a NullPointerException as there nothing left to scan on the current line, so no Toy can be created.

At this point I'm fairly lost as to what is causing this bug.
Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: this `if (readData.hasNext()) { readData.nextLine(); }` looks wrong. `hasNext()` doesn't bother if the next token is on the same line or not. So you can end up skipping a line. I suggest to either use a proper CSV parser or to read the file line by line and use the Scanner on each line separately. Then you won't have skipped lines anymore.

Comment: IMO `Scanner` is a terrible and un-intuitive API that has almost no good use cases. Forget it exists and use a `BufferedReader` to read each line and parse it using `split()` and similar methods. You'll be much better of and will be able to actually understand what's going on.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Scanner is not at fault here, but how it is used. When you use the BufferedReader with `read()` and only check for `;` and not line breaks as well, then you'll have similar issues like the question here.

Comment: @Tom: well, I agree that how it's used causes the problem here. But how it *ought* to be used is highly un-intuitive. It's a mess of an API where methods that *look* that they have something to do with each other don't and some methods simply are pointless to call at some specific times. In a way I agree and disagree with you: yes, on *can* use it correctly, but the API is designed in such a way that it's pretty hard to get to that point. This combined with the fact that it's mostly used by beginners makes me consider it a plain bad API.

Comment: Honestly I think I'll just take a couple of minutes to learn the basics of BufferedReader. Using Scanner for File/IO has been nothing but a pain so far. If it helps in the long run, I'm all for it.

Comment: You can do that Eric, yes, but I still suggest to think about a proper CSV parser instead. Reading such files manually can become troublesome in certain situations. For example: line breaks are allowed in quotes, thus reading a CSV file line by line can break such lines and you end up with incomplete lines.

Comment: @Tom I just watched a video on parsing through a CSV file and managed to get my code working perfectly with about half the lines. As you guys were saying, it wasn't really the code that was bad so much as the parsing method I was using. Thanks for the help!